# Does the shoes gem support HTTPS requests?

Tags: ruby, shoes, shoes-4

I've been looking around on how to make HTTPS requests using the Shoes GUI builder and I'm getting the `SSL_connnect` connect error and I'm unsure of what to do about it.

I made a test app in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tedma4/15e9a0591a846128db911f236a54a195)

Here's the Error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
shoes.rb:17:in `request'
shoes.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
-e:1:in `call'
```

Comment: Can you post error message as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Updating the request to strip the token and setting the verify_mode to  `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` fixed the problem.

```
token = Base64.encode64("#{user}:#{pass}").strip
uri = URI("https://example.com/")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request["authorization"] = "Bearer #{token}"
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
response = http.request(request)

info(response.body)
response
```

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of using SSL though, right?